# git push heroku master will not recognize my Gemfile.lock file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, push, gemfile

My first time pushing to Heroku using Git and I'm  getting the error message: `Gemfile.lock is required. Please run "bundle install" locally and commit your Gemfile.lock.`

I have ran `bundle install`, added the files to the `git` repo, commited the changes.  See the `Gemfile.lock` in both the repository and my directory but when I run the command `git push heroku master` it consistently throws that error.

What am I doing wrong:

Here is the git repo on my PC

```
$git ls-files
.bundle/config
.gitignore
.rspec
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
README
Rakefile
app/assets/images/rails.png
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
..<snip>..
```

Here is the git status of the repo.

```
$git status
# On branch ch_ruby_intro
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/ch_ruby_intro' by 6 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Error when I try to deploy.

```
$git push heroku master
Counting objects: 239, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (140/140), done.
Writing objects: 100% (239/239), 50.30 KiB, done.
Total 239 (delta 74), reused 215 (delta 67)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
 !
 !     Gemfile.lock is required. Please run "bundle install" locally
 !     and commit your Gemfile.lock.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Why is it not seeing the Gemfile.lock file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might it be that you're committing to the wrong branch? You're pushing master and committing to ch_ruby_intro.

Comment: Should I push `ch_ruby_intro` to heroku?

Comment: You should push to heroku the branch that contains the changes you want it to see. So I guess you should either do that or commit to master and push master.

Comment: Thanks. That was it.  Following the example in the book too literally.