# Rails Heroku Gemfile.lock error - push rejected (open source)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am trying to push my open source RoR application to Heroku but I'm having an issue making the initial push. I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073967/failed-to-deploy-redmine-to-heroku-due-to-gemfile-lock-nonexistence) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873531/deploying-rails-app-to-heroku-after-previously-taking-gemfile-lock-out-of-reposi) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605863/heroku-gemfile-lock-is-required-issue) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886044/git-push-heroku-master-will-not-recognize-my-gemfile-lock-file), but none of those answers has helped to solve my problem. I have tried `bundle update` and `bundle install` various times. I also have tried removing and then re-committing my `Gemfile.lock` file, however I get this same error still...

```
$ git push heroku master 
Counting objects: 5199, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3086/3086), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5199/5199), 4.57 MiB | 131 KiB/s, done.
Total 5199 (delta 3418), reused 3152 (delta 1962)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/NoLockfile
 !
 !     Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:frozen-springs-4725.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:frozen-springs-4725.git'
```

Since my application uses MongoDB with MongoMapper, I suspect that I have some configuration incorrect. My [code can be found here on Github](https://github.com/TheConstructors/QwikStubs/tree/heroku) (I'm currently working on the **heroku** branch). Feel free to clone our repository and try it yourself.

If anyone has any insight which could help me resolve this issue I would be very thankful!

Comment: Problem solved! It turned out it was a Git mistake on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) first.

Branches pushed to Heroku other than master will be ignored by this command. If you’re working out of another branch locally, you can either merge to master before pushing, or specify that you want to push your local branch to a remote master. To push a branch other than master, use this syntax:

```
$ git push heroku yourbranch:master
```

Comment: Ok, so even though they are on different branches Heroku still looks at my Github master branch?

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want to do. And thanks for adding the article as well

Comment: @xmpolaris at least acknowledge that you used my answer and completely changed your answer literally 3 minutes after I answered - https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjfr1nkl9baesfe/Screenshot%202013-11-10%2011.05.08.png Even if you're new here, the least you can do is not plagiarise someone else's work.

Comment: hi @Niall, I am sorry but I did not see your answer when I update my answer. I updated my answer against KJ50's comment. Anyway thanks for your comment. I will keep eye for other's work in the feature.

Answer (score 3):

Or better just run

```
git push heroku heroku:master
```

This will push your heroku branch to the master branch on heroku, which is the one heroku use's (Heroku ignores everything but the master branch).